# NG ZORROR Customize nz-date-picker Style

Tags: css, ng-zorro-antd

I am using datetimepicker of NG-ZORRO and try to customize the style:

Want to achive:

- width being responsive
- no outline when hover and focus

What I have done is:
**nzSize="large" [nzStyle]="{'width': '440px'}"**

and modify large to 50px in ng-zorro's `theme.less` file, it works but the width is fix length.

```
          <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 px-3">
                <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2"
                    for="grid-last-name">
                    Start DateTime
                </label>
                <nz-date-picker nzSize="large" [nzStyle]="{'width': '440px'}" [nzMode]="dateMode" nzShowTime (nzOnOpenChange)="handleDateOpenChange($event)"
                    (nzOnPanelChange)="handleDatePanelChange($event)">
                </nz-date-picker>
            </div>
```

[image]

See how it looks in a form, the end datetime is default input box size:

[image]

Has anyone customized before and please help!